# What does the os.path.join in python 2.7 do?

Tags: python, python-2.7, os.path

I have the following line of code which I think is not correct:

```
path_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

where `os.path.dirname(__file__)` looks for a script.

I understand that `os.path.abspath()` gives you the absolute path of a file or a directory but `os.path.join()` combines two strings together but for that we need to have 2 paths. i.e. `path_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir)))`

Am I correct in thinking that the above code is incorrect and broken?

Answer (score 3):

The `os.path.join()` call is entirely redundant, and can be safely removed. You don't need it here. It is not *technically wrong or broken* however.

`os.path.join()` accepts an *arbitrary number of arguments* (at least 1) to join together, so while it is technically permitted to pass in just the result of `os.path.dirname(__file__)`, `os.path.join()` can only return that single input.

It is probably an artefact of a code refactor or half-understood copy-and-paste action where more arguments have been removed since.

`os.path.join()` accepts a single argument for the case where you use `*args` syntax to pass in additional paths, but those extra paths are empty based on runtime conditions:

```
base = '....'
additional = ()
if some_condition:
    additional = ('additional', 'elements')
path = os.path.join(base, *additional)
```

Answer (score 0):

> os.path.join(path, *paths)
>   Join one or more path components
>   intelligently. The return value is the concatenation of path and any
>   members of *paths with exactly one directory separator (os.sep)
>   following each non-empty part except the last, meaning that the result
>   will only end in a separator if the last part is empty. If a component
>   is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and
>   joining continues from the absolute path component.

[Python 2.7 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)